# The form of Result in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
?− count_frequencies ([1 ,1 ,4 ,6 ,8 ,8 ,6 ,2 ,1] , L). 
L = [f(1,3),f(4,1),f(6,2),f(8,2),f(2,1)]
```

my question is about the form of f(1,3) I don't really understand the point. how should i do then output form in Prolog is f().
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A term of the form `f(X,N)` indicates that item `X` has frequency `N`. Given an item `X` and a list of frequencies `F`, the following predicate updates `F` to count an occurency of `X`, resulting in a new list of frequencies `G`:

```
count(X, [], [f(X,1)]).                                    % add new term
count(X, [f(X,N)|F], [f(X,M)|F]) :-  M is N+1.             % update existing term
count(X, [f(Y,N)|F], [f(Y,N)|G]) :-  X\=Y, count(X, F, G). % continue searching
```

Running example:

```
?- count(4,[],A), count(5,A,B), count(4,B,C), count(6,C,D), count(5,D,E), count(4,E,F).
A = [f(4, 1)],
B = [f(4, 1), f(5, 1)],
C = [f(4, 2), f(5, 1)],
D = [f(4, 2), f(5, 1), f(6, 1)],
E = [f(4, 2), f(5, 2), f(6, 1)],
F = [f(4, 3), f(5, 2), f(6, 1)] .
```

Now, you can use predicate `count/3` to define predicate `count_frequencies/2` as following:

```
count_frequencies(Items, Frequencies) :-
    loop(Items, [], Frequencies).

loop([], Accumulator, Accumulator).
loop([Item|Items], Accumulator, Frequencies) :-
    count(Item, Accumulator, NewAccumulator),
    loop(Items, NewAccumulator, Frequencies).
```

Running example:

```
?- count_frequencies([1 ,1 ,4 ,6 ,8 ,8 ,6 ,2 ,1] , L).
L = [f(1, 3), f(4, 1), f(6, 2), f(8, 2), f(2, 1)] ;
false.
```

Alternatively, in SWI-Prolog, you can also use predicate [`foldl/4`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=foldl/4) to define a more concise version of the predicate `count_frequencies/2`, as following:

```
another_count_frequencies(Items, Frequencies) :-
    foldl(count, Items, [], Frequencies).
```

Running example:

```
?- another_count_frequencies([1 ,1 ,4 ,6 ,8 ,8 ,6 ,2 ,1] , L).
L = [f(1, 3), f(4, 1), f(6, 2), f(8, 2), f(2, 1)] ;
false.
```

Comment: thanks actually I just need the way of the form f(1,3) . but still thanks